# Variable argument fast text search function in R

Tags: r, search, data.table, text-search

I have following sample data from a large data.table:

```
ddf = structure(list(id = 1:5, country = c("United States of America", 
 "United Kingdom", "United Arab Emirates", "Saudi Arabia", "Brazil"
 ), area = c("North America", "Europe", "Arab", "Arab", "South America"
 ), city = c("first", "second", "second", "first", "third")), .Names = c("id", 
 "country", "area", "city"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

ddf
   id                  country          area   city
1:  1 United States of America North America  first
2:  2           United Kingdom        Europe second
3:  3     United Arab Emirates          Arab second
4:  4             Saudi Arabia          Arab  first
5:  5                   Brazil South America  third
>
```

I have to make a function to which I can send variable number of text arguments and the function should perform AND searches on the data and output all rows that have all the text search arguments. Different search-strings can be in different columns.

For example searchfn(ddf, 'brazil','third') should print out the last row only.

The case needs to be ignored.

The data is large hence the search needs to be fast and speed-optimized (hence the use of data.table).

I tried:

```
searchfn = function(ddf, ...){
    ll = list(...)
    print(sapply(ll, function(x) grep(x, ddf, ignore.case=T)))
}
```

It picks up all the sent search strings and puts out searched numbers but the search is not proper.

Comment: Are you importing this data from a text file somewhere? if you're treating everything like just a bunch of text, then the data.frame/table format is getting in the way. Sounds like you'd be be better off just `grep`-ing the raw input file. you can read that into R via `pipe()` or something.

Comment: Good point. But the selected rows need to be subjected to numerical statistical analysis which cannot be done with text file at command prompt. So it may be easier to do text searches and subsetting in R itself.

Comment: I'm suggesting you filter outside of R then read into R to do the stats. Greg is great at fast text searches; and R is create for stats; neither is great for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, but I doubt it's an optimal solution:

```
searchfn = function(ddf, ...){
  ll = list(...)
  pat <- paste(unlist(ll), collapse = "|")
  X <- do.call(paste, ddf)
  Y <- regmatches(X, gregexpr(pat, X, ignore.case = TRUE))
  ddf[which(vapply(Y, function(x) length(unique(x)), 1L) == length(ll)), ]
}
```

Here are some tests to try out:

```
searchfn(ddf, 'brazil', 'third')
searchfn(ddf, 'arab', 'first')
searchfn(ddf, "united", "second")
searchfn(ddf, "united", "second", "2")
searchfn(ddf, "united", "second", "Euro")
```